# GCM messages are delivered late to the device

Tags: android, performance, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using GCM in my application. For most of the devices and users, the messages are delivered almost instantaneously, however for some users the messages are being delivered after a delay. Some times the messages are delivered immediately, some times after a delay.

I have checked that the registration id is correct.

The device is connected and all other apps receive notifications on time.

Comment: How many user ?? Maybe your server is saturated

Comment: our server sends it to GCM perfectly fine .. the delay is on GCM's end ..

Answer (score 1):

If you have `delay_while_idle` set to true, messages won't be received until the device is active.

Another reason could be that GCM may be throttling your messages in order to prevent an application from consuming excessive resources and negatively impacting battery life.

You can find more details [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html).

Comment: The push messages are not received even when the app is active. Will setting delay_while_idle to false make any difference there? Any way around throttling? This issues comes suddenly, one minute all messages are received and the next it stops working..

Answer (score 0):

GCM needs to keep a connection alive with the device but it doesn't last forever. After some period of time the connection is lost and that's when the delay occurs.

If you really need to receive the GCM messages without any delay you could keep the connection alive by periodically pinging the GCM server but this will affect the battery life.